# Why does Sendmail produce "Recipient names must be specified" error?

Tags: php, sendmail

I have a server set up with Debian 8, LAMP stack, Sendmail. It runs an instance of HumHub, which is a (PHP) social network platform. As i guess that my problem lies in the Sendmail config, I am posting here and not in some HumHub related forum. Configuring Sendmail was quite a hassle for me and i suspect i might have done something wrong. I don't just want to blindly try around, as i am happy it's running and working, all in all.

HumHub is set up to use the PHP mail function (which uses sendmail -t -i) to send out mails. Now it tries to send daily activity report mails to the users with a daily cronjob, which doesn't work, because the script it runs gives me the following error:

```
Checking for new HumHub version... done. 
Sending update e-mails to users... 20% (1/5) ETA: n/a   Recipient names must be specified
Sending update e-mails to users... done - 0 email(s) sent.
Deleting old unassigned files... done.
Deleting old notifications... done.
```

What confuses me is that Sendmail sends mails perfectly fine when i test it from the command line, so does the PHP mail function. Even HumHub successfully sends individual mails to users when they register (e.g. registration link) without any problem.
I don't think a well tested and widely used application like HumHub forgets to specify anything needed for sending an email - so where does this error come from?

Here's the /var/log/mail.log from when the error occurs (domain name and mail addresses changed):

```
Jan 10 09:12:50 serverdomain sendmail[32480]: v0A8CoBF032480: Authentication-Warning: serverdomain.de: www-data set sender to noreply@serverdomain.de using -f
Jan 10 09:12:50 serverdomain sendmail[32480]: v0A8CoBF032480: from=somename@serverdomain.de, size=37761, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=$
Jan 10 09:12:50 serverdomain sm-mta[32481]: v0A8CoAN032481: from=, size=37979, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=$
Jan 10 09:12:50 serverdomain sendmail[32480]: v0A8CoBF032480: to=somename@googlemail.com, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=67761, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1]$
Jan 10 09:12:50 serverdomain sm-mta[32483]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/$
Jan 10 09:12:50 serverdomain sm-mta[32483]: v0A8CoAN032481: to=, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=157979, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google$
Jan 10 13:40:57 serverdomain sendmail[2261]: v0ACevVp002261: from=somename@serverdomain.de, size=304, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=, relay=somename@lo$
Jan 10 13:40:57 serverdomain sm-mta[2262]: v0ACevrq002262: from=, size=542, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=, proto=ESMTP, $
Jan 10 13:40:57 serverdomain sendmail[2261]: v0ACevVp002261: to=, ctladdr=somename@serverdomain.de (1000/1000), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30$
Jan 10 13:40:58 serverdomain sm-mta[2264]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mx2.mailbox.org., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits=256/256
Jan 10 13:41:00 serverdomain sm-mta[2264]: v0ACevrq002262: to=, ctladdr= (1000/1000), delay=00:00:03, xdelay=00:00:03, mailer=esmtp, pri=12$
Jan 10 13:42:00 serverdomain sendmail[2274]: v0ACg0KE002274: from=somename@serverdomain.de, size=612, class=0, nrcpts=0, msgid=, re$
```

Sorry if i missed something important. Just tell me if you need anything (logs, etc.). Also i don't know if it makes sense to post Sendmails configs here, as this is a lot of stuff to go through and the possible causes might be more general rather then specific.

And thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you generate the relevant `TO:`/`CC:`/`BCC:` headers? `-t` instructs sendmail to extract recipients from headers.  Lack of the headers is the first possible cause to rule out.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Well, i don't generate anything. The HumHub instance has a script that's run by a cronjob and this script sends out the mails. I couldn't find any flaws in it, yet.